# How to import Kotlin/JS generated module in a separate npm-based project

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I would like to create a js library with Kotlin Multiplatform (an example of which is [this project](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/tree/main/chat), where we have a webscocket server and a js client) which I will then build as a npm package and import in my Vue project (could be any other framework).

#### what I managed to do with [chat project](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/tree/main/chat) is:

- build js sources with `./gradlew build`
- publish that via `yarn publish` (setting up remote registry url ofc)
- add published package to `package.json` with (needed to update project name to `@chat/client` by hand in the generated package.json):

```json
{
  "name": "@chat/client",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": false,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/chat-frontend",
    "packages/chat-frontend-test",
    "packages_imported/kotlin/1.6.21",
    "packages_imported/ktor-ktor-client-core-js-ir/2.0.0",
    "packages_imported/kotlin-test-js-runner/1.6.21"
  ],
  "resolutions": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {},
  "peerDependencies": {},
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "bundledDependencies": []
}
```

- added `@JsExport` annotation on `writeMessage` in src/frontendMain/kotlin/main.kt

#### what I didn't manage is (in my Vue project):

- import `writeMessage`, I exported in .kt file (it's visible in source, not exported though)
- import anything via `import * from '@chat/client'`
- or any other folder along `'@chat/client/*'`
- use the generated files in any other way

The generated package structure is very odd:

```
~ ls build/js/*

build/js/package.json  build/js/yarn.lock

build/js/node_modules:
... (npm dependencies from Kotlin/JS module)

build/js/packages:
chat-frontend  chat-frontend-test

build/js/packages_imported:
... (Kotlin/JS dependencies)
```

```
~ ls build/js/packages/chat-frontend/*

build/js/packages/chat-frontend/package.json  build/js/packages/chat-frontend/webpack.config.js

build/js/packages/chat-frontend/kotlin:
chat-frontend  chat-frontend.js  chat-frontend.js.map  chat-frontend.meta.js
(chat-frontend contains package dir tree and a file frontend.kjsm)

build/js/packages/chat-frontend/kotlin-dce:
chat-frontend.js
ktor-*.js
kotlinx-*.js
... (compiler output ???)

build/js/packages/chat-frontend/node_modules:
... (webpack cli and dev-server files)
```

Do you have any clues, tips or an example project which does that? I've processed whole section of [Kotlin/JS docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-get-started.html) but there is no information on how to import Kotlin generated .js files in a js/ts project.

**EDIT:**

I've updated my fork of `ktor-samples` with Kotlin/JS build files: `build-js` folder and `src/backendMain/resources/chat.js`. Here's the link to `chat` folder of the [fork project](https://github.com/Liczi/ktor-samples/tree/main/chat)

Comment: you can do `npm install <PATH>` where PATH is the generated JS files from your kotlin project. It would be the PATH to build folder where `js` and `map` file resides. In your case above, it would be PATH to that `build/js/packages/chat-frontend/kotlin`

Comment: isn't it the same as installing from a remote registry? I'll update the post with more info, I missed that part

Comment: yeah if you already have a remote npm module then yes, you can import that directly.

Comment: yep, and that is exactly what I'm doing, I've updated the post maybe my problem is better understandable now

Comment: can you somehow share your generated `.js` file? Want to see how the export name looks like. You would need to import the exported name like `import chatlib from chat/client`. then try `console.log(chatlib)` and see if you see the reference. here `chatlib` or whatever the exported name is something you would find in your generated `js` file.

Comment: yes, sure! I've updated the post with link to my fork, where I've just put the js build output. There are a few files that correspond to the said `chat.js` file, but the main output I guess is copied to `backendMain/resources/chat.js`. This file however seems to be minified. Thanks for helping me make sth out of this mess ;)!

Comment: what happens when you do `import chatlib from '@chat/client'` or `import * as chatlib from '@chat/client'';`

and then do `console.log(chatlib)`

Comment: @Jigar sorry for the delay, didn't notice your answer. So first of all there is a TS error: 'TS2307: Cannot find module '@chat/client' or its corresponding type declarations.'. When I Ctrl+Left click on it in Webstorm however, it takes me to the root of the dependency, where I have 'packages', 'packages_imported' and a 'package.json' as described in the post.

Comment: also I tried enforcing LEGACY compiler (instead of IR) and now I have several errors: ' Can't resolve imported dependency "kotlin"' and kotlin and ktor libraries. Plus 'Could not find a declaration file for module '@chat/client'. .../node_modules/@chat/client/kotlin/chat-frontend.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/chat__client` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@chat/client';`'

Answer (score 1):

I will try to help

1. Kotlin/JS has 2 kinds of compiler: legacy and IR. `@JsExport` affects only IR compiler. But from `kotlin-dce` folder, you use `legacy` compiler backend. In IR compiler, DCE (dead code elimination) is included into compiler and there is no folder `kotlin-dce`. You can change compiler kind in `gradle.properties` with `kotlin.js.compiler=ir|legacy`.
2. When you build project with IR, `packages/*/kotlin` will fully contain your library (similar with legacy's `kotlin-dce`)
3. Then you need to prepare appropriate `package.json` file with `name` and `main` fields (task `:publicPackageJson` could help with that, but check, if it is ok for your case)
4. Now in Kotlin/JS export works with packages. It means, that if you export `io.ktor.samples.chat.frontend.writeMessage`, it will be exported as `io.ktor.samples.chat.frontend.writeMessage` in js. So to import it, you need import `io` and then find necessary declarations.

```
import { io } from '@chat/client`

io.ktor.samples.chat.frontend.writeMessage("hello")
```

Comment: I tried just copying packages and packages_imported and a generated package.json (changed name and private: false) and publishing it, but "warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects." plus "TS2307: Cannot find module '@signalling/client' or its corresponding type declarations.". Adding updateted package.json used for publishing.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of classical (non-IR) js backend usage and you use only non-private NPM dependencies then the only thing that you need is to compile your Kotlin/js library (via `:compileKotlinJs` task), generate `package.json` for your library (via `:publicPackageJson`) and your package could be published to NPM or another private repository (by `yarn publish`).

After publication, you will have the ability to set your library as a dependency in any js project. (Note that the name and version of your library will be placed inside `package.json` (generated by `:publicPackageJson` task)).

Also, you can check [this discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-js-1-4-how-to-output-a-npm-package/19128). Hope it will help you.

Comment: hey Artem, thanks for the reply. I was able to publish the package, but cannot import the contents of it in another NPM-based project (please see comments under the post).